# Projective limit of Fréchet reflexive spaces

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

I am reading this paper, constructing spaces of functions and distributions with exponential growth on Fréchet nuclear spaces and their dual.

[Un théorème de dualité entre espaces de fonctions holomorphes à croissance exponentielle, Journal of Functional Analysis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123699935188)

The proof of Proposition 2 page 7 mentions that some space is Fréchet and reflexive as a projective limit of topological vector spaces with the same property. For this to be true for Fréchet spaces, we would need the limit to be over a countable set of indices, and it does not seem to be the case. The proposition should be true as I guess we can restrict to a countable set of indices, and as the space is latter shown to be nuclear and thus reflexive if Fréchet. However, I was wondering if I was missing something about the stability of Fréchet and reflexive spaces. Are they stable by projective limits ?

Comment: Of course, only countable limits of Fréchet spaces are Fréchet (for example, a product $\mathbb R^I$ is the projective limit of finite dimensional spaces $\mathbb R^E$ with $E\subseteq I$ finite, but $\mathbb R^I$ is metrizable if and only if $I$ is countable), but this seems to be the case in the proposition you mention.

Comment: ok, I might have misread, I supposed the m in the index was real but in fact it may not be. thanks !